# Laravel 7 Multi auth // how to create different registration page and table?

Tags: php, laravel

I can add new users registration with different table and registration page. But when i send registration from "register/blogger" it create account to users table not to blogger. I create auth through `php artisan ui vue --auth`. How to edit auth default to multi ?

Thanks for help.

auth.php

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            //'hash' => true,
        ],

        'blogger' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'bloggers',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],

        'bloggers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'table' => 'bloggers',
            'model' => App\Blogger::class,
        ],
    ],

 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    'bloggers' => [
        'provider' => 'bloggers',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

RegisterController.php

```
public function showBloggerRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register1');
    }

protected function createBlogger(array $data)
    {
        return Blogger::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

and this is my route web.php blogger

```
Auth::routes();
.
.
.

Route::get('/register/blogger', 'Auth\RegisterController@showBloggerRegisterForm');

Route::post('/login/blogger', 'Auth\LoginController@bloggerLogin');

Route::view('/blogger', 'blogger');
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I created ''blogger" in auth.php, created "createBlogger()" and showBloggerRegistrerForm() to registerController.php and settings routes in web.php

Comment: your controller is probably on the web middleware by default, you would probably need to override this. would it not be easier to add a user group than to have a separate concept of authentication?

Comment: @MHewison Yes i understand. It is possible user group with diffrent tabel and registration pages ? and do you have any tutorial ?

Comment: I believe you can just use ```Auth::guard('blogger')->user()``` instead of ```Auth::user();```

Comment: @MHewison in web.php i have Auth::routes(); and this replace with uth::guard('blogger')->user() ?